# Google Maps Flutter Gestures Three finger swipe

Tags: flutter, google-maps, maps, gesture

I am using google maps flutter plugin for my flutter mobile app. It works fine but when i take a screenshot of the map using three fingers vertical swipe across the screen (As is the gesture for all/most Redmi Phones), the map then stops responding to any gesture at all (scrolling, zooming, etc. nothing works). It stays frozen until i reload the page. I have added some gestures like

```
body: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(lat,long ), zoom: 12),
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                  compassEnabled: true,
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                  gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())
                ),
```

Comment: Can you post your whole code? What is the widget before the GoogleMap widget?

Comment: GoogleMap Widget is the only widget I have in the body of this screen

Comment: In android Studio flutter code, this is the error i get if i try scrolling after a screenshot
`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
_AndroidMotionEventConverter.toAndroidMotionEvent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:594:73)`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same problem

Comment: Some solves https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69431 , 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/72611 and
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71354